# How to debug a cast execption in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I am getting a cast exception and I have re-written this code a large number of times. I am getting the exception on the following line:

```
If (CInt(hHurricaneYear) < CInt(_strYears(hAverage))) Then
```

And I am only getting results in the `lblNumberOfHurricans`.  the other two labels are not showing any results.  I thought I was getting it when the cast exception showed up.

Can anyone suggest how to get the results and stop the exception?

Here is what I have so far (well at least the last try).

```
Option Strict On

Public Class frmHurricaneStatistics

    '   Class level Private variables.
    Public Shared _intSizeOfArray As Integer = 20
    Private _strYears(_intSizeOfArray) As String
    Private _intNumberOfHurricans(_intSizeOfArray) As Integer

    Private Sub frmHurricaneStatistics_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs
                                            ) Handles MyBase.Load

        '   This load event reads the inventory text file and fills
        '   the ComboBox object with the Hurricane Statistics.

        '   Initialize an instace of the streamreader object and declare variables.
        Dim objReader As IO.StreamReader
        Dim strHurricaneStatistics As String = "Hurricanes.txt"
        Dim intCount As Integer = 0
        Dim intFill As Integer
        Dim strFileError As String = "The file is not available. Please restart the
            application when the file is available."

        '   Verify the Hurricane.txt file exists.
        If IO.File.Exists(strHurricaneStatistics) Then
            objReader = IO.File.OpenText(strHurricaneStatistics)

            '   Read the file line by line until the file is completed.
            Do While objReader.Peek <> -1
                _strYears(intCount) = objReader.ReadLine()
                _intNumberOfHurricans(intCount) = Convert.ToInt32(objReader.ReadLine())
                intCount += 1
            Loop
            objReader.Close()

            '   The ComboBox objext is filled with the Years for Hurricanes.
            For intFill = 0 To (_strYears.Length - 1)
                cmbYears.Items.Add(_strYears(intFill))
            Next
        Else
            MsgBox(strFileError, , "Error")
            Close()

            '  If ComboBox is filled then enable the Display Statistics button.
            'btnDisplayStatistics.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDisplayStatistics_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs
                                           ) Handles btnDisplayStatistics.Click

        '   This click event calls the sub procedures for the selected years and
        '   the number of hurricans in that year.
        Dim intSelectedYear As Integer
        Dim strMissingSelection As String = "Missing Selection"
        Dim strSelectAYearError As String = "Please Select a Year"

        '   If the ComboBox object has a selection, Display Statistics.
        If cmbYears.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
            intSelectedYear = cmbYears.SelectedIndex
        Else
            MsgBox(strSelectAYearError, , strMissingSelection)
        End If


Private Sub btnDisplayStatistics_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs
                                           ) Handles btnDisplayStatistics.Click

        '   This click event calls the sub procedures for the selected years and
        '   the number of hurricans in that year.
        Dim intSelectedYear As Integer
        Dim strMissingSelection As String = "Missing Selection"
        Dim strSelectAYearError As String = "Please Select a Year"

        '   If the ComboBox object has a selection, call the Display Statistics procedure.
        If cmbYears.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
            intSelectedYear = cmbYears.SelectedIndex
        Else
            MsgBox(strSelectAYearError, , strMissingSelection)
        End If

        '   This procedure MakeLabelsVisible Is called to display the labels
        '   And the results.
        MakeLabelsVisible()

        Dim hHurricaneAverage As Integer
        Dim hHurricaneYear As Integer = 0

        For hAverage As Integer = 0 To _strYears.Length - 1
            If (CInt(hHurricaneYear) < CInt(_strYears(hAverage))) Then
                hHurricaneYear = CInt(CType(CInt(_strYears(hAverage)), String))
            End If
            hHurricaneAverage = hHurricaneAverage + CInt((_strYears.ToString))

            hHurricaneAverage = CInt(hHurricaneAverage / _strYears.Length)
        Next

        '   Display the statistics for the Storm Average in the selected Year
        '   and the most active year within the range of year.

        lblNumberOfHurricanes.Text = "The Number of Hurricanes in the Year " &
            _strYears(intSelectedYear) & " is " & _intNumberOfHurricans(intSelectedYear).ToString() & "."
        lblAvergeNumberHurricanes.Text = "The Average Number of Storms was " &
            hHurricaneAverage & " Hurricanes."

        Dim intSizeOfArray As Integer = Nothing
        lblMostStorms.Text = "The Year "(CInt(_strYears(CInt(hHurricaneYear.ToString())) & " 
            Had The Most Storms Between " & (_strYears(0) & _strYears(20).ToString)))

    End Sub
Option strict on
```

Comment: what is the value of  `_strYears(hAverage)` when it bombs?   You *might* get it on the line you indicate if whatever is at that index cant be converted to integer, but you ***will*** get the exception on `CInt((_strYears.ToString))`.  If  `_strYears` is an array, then `_strYears.ToString` will result in `"System.String[]"` which can't be converted to an integer.    Since you know you are going to be doing math with it, that array should be integers.  Also, you are throwing away the fractional portion of the average and `CInt(hHurricaneYear)` is pointless because `hHurricaneYear` is an integer.

Comment: Hi there, I am really confused.  what you are saying makes sense.  I am tying to get an average of the hurricanes.txt file and display it in the label NumberOfHurricanes. and then using the same txt file get the year with the most hurricans which is year 2005.

Comment: Hi there. I am sorry I should have included the first part of this mess.  can you look at it again and see what I have made an error on.

Comment: Hi Miranda, have you checked the answer below?

Comment: Move the code in the form load event to a button click so any exceptions show up.  And you should learn the basics of Classes - storing data in parallel arrays is very 1990s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error lies in that you are trying to convert an entire string array into an integer:

```
hHurricaneAverage = hHurricaneAverage + CInt((_strYears.ToString))
```

You will need to call the index of _strYears:

```
hHurricaneAverage = hHurricaneAverage + CInt((_strYears(hAverage).ToString))
```

This will also explain why the other labels do not update, because hHurricanAverage never gets calculated.

Comment: Hi there.  I have changed the code.  and I am not getting a cast execption.  however my average is now 1 when it should be 12..  Thank you for all your help.. I really appricate it.

Comment: This is what I have now.
        Dim hHurricaneAverage As Integer
        Dim hHurricaneYear As Integer = 0

        For hAverage As Integer = 0 To _intNumberOfHurricans.Length - 1
            If hHurricaneYear < _intNumberOfHurricans(hAverage) Then
                hHurricaneYear = _intNumberOfHurricans(hAverage)
            End If
            hHurricaneAverage = hHurricaneAverage + _intNumberOfHurricans(hAverage)

            hHurricaneAverage = CInt(hHurricaneAverage / _intNumberOfHurricans.Length)
        Next

Comment: Is it supposed to be For hAverage As Integer = 0 to _strYears.length -1 instead?